# Better Player Starts again and again when ever i go scroll down

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the better player plugin to show videos it' works fine but the problem is whenever I try to scroll down the screen and then back the video starts again and I don't know what causes that is there any help THANKS :)

my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: _betterPlayerController == null
          ? CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: widget.loaderColor,
              backgroundColor: widget.loaderBackgroundColor,
            )
          : AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              child: BetterPlayer(
                controller: _betterPlayerController as BetterPlayerController,
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have never used better player, but I think your problem is coming from a setState, do you have anything that is listening to the scrollController ?

Comment: thanks, bro for your response I found the error it was listView it destroys the building all the way so I have to use it singlechildscrollview with column that helped me

Comment: @ahmedmohamedabdulkadir hey man, are you sure that solved the problem? I have the same issue and it doesn't work using the SingleChildScrollView. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572695/flutter-betterplayer-stops-playing-when-scrolling-down