# Flutter BetterPlayer stops playing when scrolling down

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen a similiar topic with the same problem [Better Player Starts again and again when ever i go scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69659991/better-player-starts-again-and-again-when-ever-i-go-scroll-down), but the solution doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              header(),
              body(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

The `header()` contains the video and the `body()` contains the text (which can be long). By scrolling down, the video will stop and I don't want that.

I have also tried to use a ListView instead of a SingleChildScrollView, but the behavior is the same.

The video is loaded this way:

```
Widget header() 
{
    BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSourceType.NETWORK,
      widget.banner.file.url,
    );
    betterPlayerController = new BetterPlayerController(
      BetterPlayerConfiguration(
        autoPlay: true,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
          enableOverflowMenu: false,
          enableSkips: false,
        ),
        autoDispose: false,
      ),
      betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource,
    );

    return Hero(
      tag: 'banner-' + widget.banner.id.toString(),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 300,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
          child: BetterPlayer(
            controller: betterPlayerController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

Digging into the BetterPlayer code (I'm using an old version of 0.3.3), the plugin was pausing automatically the video if the visibility of the player was zero during the scroll.

To solve it, two things must be rectified.

1 - Apply a configuration that states that if the visibility of player is none, do nothing (no pause)

```
betterPlayerController = new BetterPlayerController(
  BetterPlayerConfiguration(
    playerVisibilityChangedBehavior: (double visibility) {
        // do nothing
    },
  ),
);
```

2 - When disposing the plugin, must pause first, otherwise since we say "do nothing if no visibility" it will continue to play the video

```
@override
void dispose() {
    if (betterPlayerController != null) {
      betterPlayerController.pause();
      betterPlayerController.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
}
```